# Удобное включение переменной в строку

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Всем привет.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какой-нибудь хоткей или плагин в intellij idea, чтобы быстро  включать переменную в строку?

Например, есть строка "Все хорошо, значение переменной=", и приходится
писать в эту строку "Все хорошо, значение переменной= **" +variable +"**."

PS: про soutv знаю, но в большинстве случаев это не подходит, особенно когда надо добавить переменную в уже существующую строку

Comment: этот способ `StringBuilder` или `String.format` :)

Comment: Прошу прочитать вопрос еще раз

Comment: Можно просто перейти на PHP.

Comment: Тогда уж на груви/котлин, там это все в стандартном пакете есть

Comment: а если использовать заменить или ЗаменитьВсё ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил Live Template:

```
Abbreviation: ++
Description: Insert variable into string
Expand with: Enter
Template text: "+ $EXPR$ +" (кавычки тоже)
Edit Template Variable: 
expression:variableOfType("") default Value: "expr"
```

[Скрин настроек](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMJ27.jpg)

Работает так: пишешь ++ в строке, жмешь Enter(хоткей можно поменять в настройках), и выбираешь переменную.